# SqlConnection Fails Due to Event Log Permissions

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, sqlconnection

I created a program for our uses to use on their office computers.  When they try to use the program it throws an exception from the SqlConnection constructor that says 'Registry access is not allowed'.

Our network admin has restricted user access to the registry to prevent people from installing personal software.  Additionally, I have no need to write to the event log.  Is there some why to tell SqlConnection to not attempt to access the event log?

Source Code:

```
string _ConnectionString = "server=our_server_name; initial catalog=our_db_name; integrated security=true;"
...
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString)) <-- exception thrown here
{
    connection.Open();
    ...
}
```

Exception

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory' threw an exception. 
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters' threw an exception. 
 ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.
 at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable)
 at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.FindCustomCategory(String category, PerformanceCounterCategoryType& categoryType)
 at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.IsCustomCategory(String machine, String category)
 at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.InitializeImpl()
 at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.set_RawValue(Int64 value)
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolCounters.Counter..ctor(String categoryName, String instanceName, String counterName, PerformanceCounterType counterType)
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolCounters..ctor(String categoryName, String categoryHelp)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters..ctor()
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters..cctor()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory..cctor()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..cctor()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor()
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString, SqlCredential credential)
 at OurProgram.Form1.UpdateStuff() in C:\path_to_project\Form1.cs:line 111
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information about the actual exception.  What type of exception is it (i.e. the inner exception on the `System.TypeInitializationException`)?  What is the full error message?

Comment: It actually looks like in .net 4.6 there is code to support your particular bug http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/PerformanceCounterLib.cs,dceb05845090520b, the exception you have there IS being caught. At least in .net 4.6.

Comment: @roryap, from what I posted you can see the exception is a SecurityException and there are inner exceptions of type TypeInitializationException.  I had copied everything that was in the dialog box.  So I don't have any more details to the exception to include.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to upgrade to .net 4.6 as it seems that particular code path has had a try catch added to it since you last upgraded to the latest .net framework.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/PerformanceCounterLib.cs,dceb05845090520b

```
                    if (baseKey != null) {
                        try {
                            key = baseKey.OpenSubKey(keyPath);
                        } catch (SecurityException) {
                            // we may not have permission to read the registry key on the remote machine.  The security exception  
                            // is thrown when RegOpenKeyEx returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED or ERROR_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
                            //
                            // In this case we return an 'Unknown' category type and 'false' to indicate the category is *not* custom.
                            //
                            categoryType = PerformanceCounterCategoryType.Unknown;
                            this.customCategoryTable[category] = categoryType;
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
```

Additionally if your network admin gives you any stick about not supporting the upgrade. Then tell him that Microsoft are dropping support for .net 4.0 early 2016. So its only a matter of time :D

> .NET Framework 4: .NET Framework 4 did not ship in any operating
>   system. .NET Framework 4 is supported on Windows Server 2003 SP2 until
>   July 14, 2015, and Windows Vista SP2, Windows 7 SP1, Windows Server
>   2008 SP2, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows 8.1 Update, Windows
>   Server 2012, and Windows Server 2012 R2 until January 12, 2016.

Comment: I'm not sure this'll help.  From looking at the source it returns false from the catch block to IsCustomCategory.  IsCustomCategory would then returns false to InitializeImpl.  InitializeImpl would then throw InvalidOperationException. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/PerformanceCounter.cs,3a0253acf2670c70.  I'll see if I can get .NET 4.6 installed on somones computer to test this.

Comment: Overall however SQL should probably not run directly from a client machine. Perhaps you could design a server client setup...

Comment: I do usually do a server/client approach.  However, this is something I threw together to grab data from a legacy database for a new federal reporting requirement.  They want data from the past 8 years.  Going forward we'll only be reporting the prior year from the production database.  So we won't even need this program after this month.  Anyway, I tried .NET 4.6 but that didn't work.  I'll just use the 'run as' option to run it under my credentials until they are done using it.